# 'Blog Archive' suddenly appeared on custom post type; how to remove

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have all of a sudden started seeing `Blog Archives Post navigation` (as below) rather than every post in that custom post type. I changed something in the Wordpress SEO plugin which has since been deactivated.

The particular custom post type is a Testimonial from wootheme's testimonials plugin.

Does anyone know how i return this to normal rather than showing each post as a page (the page below is p1 of 2 for example)?

> Blog Archives Post navigation ← Older posts John, Manchester
>
> (the content) Great service and really comfortable journey. Would definitely
>   recommend. Post navigation ← Older posts Archives
>
> Meta

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other plugin such as WP Page Navi that handle a custom pagination?

Comment: @JMa Hi, no there isn't, just Yoats SEO plugin and Wordpress SEO.